# Capture a row number before change VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I just started writing `VBA` code and I am facing a problem. The code works without any problem if i.e. I am in cell `b11` and switch to cell `a2` or `c2`. But if I write something in cell `b2` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then the code doesn't work. I assume this happens because of `ActiveCell.row`. How can I make it happen to work even when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

P.S. I need the `ActiveCell.Row` so i can get the cell number in the `MsgBox` error.

```
Sub Change()

Dim i As Long

i = ActiveCell.Row

If (Cells(i, "B") + Cells(i, "D")) <> Cells(i, "F") Then
    MsgBox "B" & i & " + D" & i & " must equal cell F" & i & " which is: " & Range("W" & i).Value

    Cells(i, "B").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Cells(i, "D").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Else
    Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "D")).Interior.Color = RGB(1000, 1000, 1000)
End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B11:F10000"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
   Call Change
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the code to work when you modify cell "B2", you need to modify your Range in the scanned range in `Worksheet_Change` event.

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B11:F10000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
   Change Target.Row ' call change and pass the row number
End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Change(i As Long)
' get the row number directly from the worksheet_change event

If (Cells(i, "B") + Cells(i, "D")) <> Cells(i, "F") Then
    MsgBox "B" & i & " + D" & i & " must equal cell F" & i & " which is: " & Range("W" & i).Value

    Cells(i, "B").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Cells(i, "D").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Else
    Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "D")).Interior.Color = RGB(1000, 1000, 1000)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That was a mistake in the comment. The code should work from 'B11'. So, I write the data in cell 'B11' i.e. 10. If I press Enter afterwards, it goes to cell 'B12' and the code doesn't work. Instead if I select with my pad cell 'C11' or 'A11' the code works, because my mouse stays on the same line which is 11. If I press Enter, it goes to line 12 and the code doesn't work. I am pretty sure it has do to with the ActiveCell.Row function

Comment: @georgec not sure when you write "I write the data in cell 'B11' i.e. 10" , what is 10 ? when I am typing in cell "B11" the code above works. Can you explain ?

Comment: Fixed it. No problems now. Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes. I did that :)

Answer (score 0):

Please start over and make sure your event handler works as it should. Add this in an empty worksheet to try.

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "You just changed " & Target.Address
End Sub
```

Note that this event handler MUST reside in this sheet's private module:

[image]

More info here:
http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm